# Wordpress get post id with a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, reveal.js

I have been stuck on this for weeks. I have an HTML slide presentation using Reveal.js. I want to run a php script on the very last slide.

This is an HTML button on the last slide within a Wordpress post:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open php file</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("../../testing/test.php", "_self");
}
</script>
```

This is the code inside the test.php file that I am trying to run but it returns null:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../wp-load.php');
echo "Post ID: ".get_the_ID(); // Returns nulls but I want this to return 86.
```

The post id is 86. I can hard code it into the html (if I have to) but I don't want to hard code it into the php file. Also, I would prefer not to use jquery. How can I get the post id into the php file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using global $post variable??

```
global $post;
```

And after that, you can get the id,

```
echo "Post ID: ".$post->
```

Another approach is using `$wpdb` global variable to make database queries.

You can also use JavaScript to send your post id to another php file using javaScript forms, Ajax or jQuery. [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Maybe the most easiest approach for you is something like this

```
function myJavascriptFunction() { 
  var javascriptVariable = "John";
  window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + javascriptVariable; 
}
```

On your myphpfile.php you can use `$_GET['name']` after your javascript was executed.

Comment: Yes, I tried many variations of using globals. They all return null. I think the problem is that the php is not being loaded within the post. It is run directly from the server within the core files of the site. The php file is outside of the wordpress installation.

Comment: If it is outside the wordpress, then you should use DB queries using global $wpdb. This link could be a help. https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-databases-in-wordpress/

Comment: Good idea. I never thought of that. However, I think that would require making many php files to handle each post. I would like to only use one php to handle each post for each user. How would I query that last post that the user was reading?

Comment: Maybe, it would be easier to create a variable in JS and pass it to the php file. How could I do that?